# Как вручную сделать merge каждого файла по отдельности выбирая в каждом случае нужную версию?

Tags: git

**Дано:**

Коммиты master: А -> C -> B, test: A -> C; Файл X изменён и в `B` и в `C` по разному.

**Задача:**

Получить в master файл X в виде из коммита `C`.

**Проблема:**

При слиянии веток файл Х получается в версии коммита `B`

**Вопрос:**

Как вручную при merge выбрать версию файла/строки в файле, т.е. переопределить поведение по умолчанию?

Comment: Возможен вариант переноса коммита? git cherry-pick?

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́, бегло просмотрел гугловую выдачу по поводу команды, но не уверен, что до конца понял как оно работает(

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я с гитом слабо дружу, но вот, могу скриншот с gitHub приложить. Там видно, что будут удалены строки, а мне надо наоборот( https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn50it5y1na6pfp/git.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поискал, но не нашёл где посмотреть дерево( На bitBucket. вроде, видел, а тут не нашёл(

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот ссылка на дерево и репо: https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger/network

Comment: @ЮрийСПб исправил вопрос так, чтобы он верно отражал произошедшее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо, многое стало понятнее. И всё это из-за кодеров из гугла кои в ссвоих апдейтах косячат(((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что test - это родитель для master. Все коммиты из test уже входят в master, и операция слияния ничего не делает.

То, что вам требуется, называется не "слияние" - а "выборочный откат версии файла". В гите это делается одной из форм команды checkout:

```
git checkout test (путь к файлу)
```

Документация: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: Угу, спс, кажется это то что нужно, ща пробовать буду)

Comment: Попробовал - получилось, спасибо! =)